# PHP script for JSON for use with fullcalendar

Tags: php, jquery, json, parsing, fullcalendar

I'm trying to display the following JSON string with a php script:

```
{ id:1, start:"10:00", end:"12:00", dow:[1,4],
  ranges[{start:"2015/03/01", end:"2015/04/01"}]
}
```

But I am unsure how to code the php script to display the 'start' and 'end' range values.

```
for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {

    $event_array[] = array(
        'id' => $record[$i]['id'],
        'start' => $record[$i]['start_time'],
        'end' => $record[$i]['end_time'],
        'dow' => $record[$i]['dow'],
        'rangeStart' => $record[$i]['start_date'],
        'rangeEnd' => $record[$i]['end_date'],
        'allDay' => false
    );
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you have so far. It's basically just building an array (multi level) with the data structure you want, then converting it to json

Comment: updated with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an array in the following format:

```
$array = [
    "id"        => $id,
    "start"     => $start,
    "end"       => $end,
    "dow"       => $dow,
    "ranges"    => [
        "start" => $rangeStart,
        "end"   => $rangeEnd
    ],
    "allDay"    => $allDay
];
```

then just call `json_encode($array)` to convert it to a json string.